# Smooth algebraic functions

Tags: reference-request, real-algebraic-geometry

Suppose $f(x)=\sum_{|\alpha|=0}^{\infty}a_{\alpha} x^{\alpha}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Moreover we know a priori that $f$ is an algebraic function.
Is $f$ necessarily a polynomial?If not what are typical counterexamples?

Comment: What do you mean by algebraic?  Algebraic over the ring of polynomial functions on $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: Algebraic function in [this](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebraic_function) sense.

Comment: I think if you have convergence for all $x$ in $\mathbb R^n$, you will have bounds on the coefficients that would make it absolutely convergent for all $x$ in $\mathbb C^n$. An algebraic function will have at most polynomial growth, so Cauchy's theorem should imply that high degree coefficients vanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote a series. If you mean that it converges for all $x\in R^n$ than this is an entire
function that is the series also converges for $x\in C^n$. An entire algebraic function is
a polynomial, indeed. This follows from the growth estimate and Cauchy's inequalities, for example.

Comment: I cannot agree with you more.corrected it.and thanks for the answer.